# How can I tell if a certain IIS configuration key has been imported?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm building some configuration management scripts that need to be idempotent.  I need to check if the IIS keys for the web farm have been imported on a server and if not import them.

I've got the commands to do the import, but I can't seem to find a consistent way to check that a particular set of keys has been imported.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'm coming up with at this point is to export the IIS keys from the server with

```
aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "D:\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -pri
```

and compare the files, but that is kind of heavyweight to run frequently through the day as my configuration management tool checks the state of the system.  I could put a timer on it, like only export every hour or every eight hours, but then I can't catch deviations as quickly.